# Cannot delete registry key

Tags: c#, key, registry

I'm struggling with something really simple. I want to delete an entire registry key through a little console application. `Application` is the key I want to delete, regardless of the values it contains:

[image: Path]

This is what I did, but the `subKey` value always seems to be null:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        string keyPath = "SOFTWARE\\Apps";
        var hklm = Registry.LocalMachine;
        var subKey = hklm.OpenSubKey(keyPath, true);

        if(subKey != null)
        {
            subKey.DeleteSubKey("Application");
            Console.WriteLine("DELETED");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NOT FOUND");
        }
}
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing? I've already looked for other answers but no luck at all.

Comment: "*Is there something obvious I'm missing*" yes most likely.. and that would be registry virtualization https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/32-bit-and-64-bit-application-data-in-the-registry i have answered a couple of questions on this, and there are many duplicates, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryview?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @TheGeneral I absolutely have neglected this. I made some changes to the code and I actually managed to delete the key. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions in the comments, I managed to delete the key from the registry. What I was missing was to explicitly tell the system I wanted to use the 64-bit version registry view.

I had to change the code as the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        string keyPath = "SOFTWARE\\Apps";
        var subKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(keyPath, true); // This method accepts the RegistryView parameter.

        if (subKey != null)
        {
            subKey.DeleteSubKey("Application");
            Console.WriteLine("DELETED");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NOT FOUND");
        }
}
```